# Should the duplicate flag be removed if the target question doesn't answer the same thing?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicates

I came searching for the question *what should a North American driver know when driving in Europe for the first time*, and the following question:

[What should someone from the US know when driving in Italy?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57313/what-are-must-know-rules-for-driving-in-italy-as-opposed-to-driving-in-usa?lq=1)

It was marked as duplicate to the then-titled "[What are the main differences in traffic regulations between the US/Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/711/what-are-the-main-differences-in-traffic-regulations-between-the-us-europe)", to which the questions asks and the answers recount *what a European should know when driving in the United States*, which is the reverse.

As a result, my question has been asked but marked as a duplicate with the answer of exactly the reverse of what I wanted to know.

Should the duplicate flag be removed?

Comment: We have a system for this. It's the reopen flag. Add a comment about why it's not a duplicate, and vote to reopen. Unfortunately sometimes people make mistakes.

Comment: @MarkMayo how do you actually do that? I've never been able to find that button

Comment: @J.Constantine it's usually under the question - along with 'share', 'edit', 'close'. Maybe there's a rep qualification for it? IN that case you can flag it for a mod to consider for reopening.

Comment: @MarkMayo Indeed, I would've voted for re-open, but the reopen vote privilege is around 3k rep from my StackOverflow memory which I'm not even close to have, hence this question.

Comment: Ack, another crazy case of blatant "close as duplicate" abuse. Why does this [keep happening here](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3482/can-we-be-more-careful-in-marking-duplicates-on-questions-that-are-related-but-a)? Glad to see this one got reopened eventually.

Answer (score 1):

> Ack, another crazy case of blatant "close as duplicate" abuse. Why does this keep happening here? Glad to see this one got reopened eventually. – user568458 May 10 at 23:35

May be time for a [status-completed] tag.